# Multiple Client Threads can connect, threads are accepted in sequential order

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to write a bidding application, and have a server (and thread handler), and Client (and client handler).
Currently, multiple clients can connect fine, but the first client to connect gets the opening messages, and only after the first client has proceeded to the 3rd interaction(between Client and Server), does the next Client in the list get the starting message.
I'm not entirely sure what's causing it, as it's adding a new thread each time. It's simply not showing contents of writeUTF() to all the clients at the same time.

I want to know what I'm doing wrong, and why I can't get multiple clients to start the auction at the same time. Here's my code. 
Client Thread and Client

```
  import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Client implements Runnable
{  private Socket socket              = null;
   private Thread thread              = null;
   private BufferedReader  console   = null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;
   private ClientThread client    = null;
   private String chatName;


   public Client(String serverName, int serverPort, String name)
   {
      System.out.println("Establishing connection. Please wait ...");

      this.chatName = name;
      try{
         socket = new Socket(serverName, serverPort);
         System.out.println("Connected: " + socket);
         start();
      }
      catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
          System.out.println("Host unknown: " + uhe.getMessage());
      }
      catch(IOException ioe){
          System.out.println("Unexpected exception: " + ioe.getMessage());
      }
   }

   public void run()
   {
       while (thread != null){
         try {
            //String message = chatName + " > " + console.readLine();
            String message = console.readLine();
            streamOut.writeUTF(message);
            streamOut.flush();
         }
         catch(IOException ioe)
         {  System.out.println("Sending error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            stop();
         }
      }
   }

   public void handle(String msg)
   {  if (msg.equals(".bye"))
      {  System.out.println("Good bye. Press RETURN to exit ...");
         stop();
      }
      else
         System.out.println(msg);
   }

   public void start() throws IOException
   {
      console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      if (thread == null)
      {  client = new ClientThread(this, socket);
         thread = new Thread(this);
         thread.start();
      }
   }

   public void stop()
   {
      try
      {  if (console   != null)  console.close();
         if (streamOut != null)  streamOut.close();
         if (socket    != null)  socket.close();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {
          System.out.println("Error closing ...");

      }
      client.close();
      thread = null;
   }


   public static void main(String args[])
   {  Client client = null;
      if (args.length != 3)
         System.out.println("Usage: java Client host port name");
      else
         client = new Client(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), args[2]);
   }
}

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
```

Client Thread

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread
{  private Socket           socket   = null;
   private Client       client   = null;
   private DataInputStream  streamIn = null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;
   private BufferedReader console;
   private String message, bidMessage;




    public ClientThread(Client _client, Socket _socket)
       {  client   = _client;
          socket   = _socket;
          open();
          start();
       }
       public void open()
       {  try
          {
              streamIn  = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
              String auction = streamIn.readUTF(); // Commence auction/
              System.out.println(auction);
              String item = streamIn.readUTF();
              System.out.println(item);

              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
              streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
              message = scanner.next();
              streamOut.writeUTF(message);
              streamOut.flush();

             String reply = streamIn.readUTF();
             System.out.println(reply);






             bidMessage = scanner.next();
             streamOut.writeUTF(bidMessage);
             streamOut.flush();



          }
          catch(IOException ioe)
          {
             System.out.println("Error getting input stream: " + ioe);
             client.stop();
          }
       }
       public void close()
       {  try
          {  if (streamIn != null) streamIn.close();
          }
          catch(IOException ioe)
          {  System.out.println("Error closing input stream: " + ioe);
          }
       }

       public void run()
       {
           while (true && client!= null){
              try {

                  client.handle(streamIn.readUTF());
              }
              catch(IOException ioe)
              {
                  client = null;
                  System.out.println("Listening error: " + ioe.getMessage());

             }
          }
       }
    }
```

BidServer

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BidServer implements Runnable
{  

   // Array of clients  
   private BidServerThread clients[] = new BidServerThread[50];
   private ServerSocket server = null;
   private Thread       thread = null;
   private int clientCount = 0;

   public BidServer(int port)
   {
      try {

         System.out.println("Binding to port " + port + ", please wait  ...");
         server = new ServerSocket(port);
         System.out.println("Server started: " + server.getInetAddress());
         start();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {
          System.out.println("Can not bind to port " + port + ": " + ioe.getMessage());

      }
   }

   public void run()
   {
      while (thread != null)
      {
         try{

            System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");

            addThread(server.accept());

            int pause = (int)(Math.random()*3000);
            Thread.sleep(pause);

         }
         catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Server accept error: " + ioe);
            stop();
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
         }
      }
   }

  public void start()
    {
        if (thread == null) {
          thread = new Thread(this);
          thread.start();
       }
    }

   public void stop(){
       thread = null;

   }

   private int findClient(int ID)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < clientCount; i++)
         if (clients[i].getID() == ID)
            return i;
      return -1;
   }

   public synchronized void broadcast(int ID, String input)
   {
       if (input.equals(".bye")){
          clients[findClient(ID)].send(".bye");
          remove(ID);
       }
       else
         for (int i = 0; i < clientCount; i++){
            if(clients[i].getID() != ID)
                clients[i].send(ID + ": " + input); // sends messages to clients
        }
       notifyAll();
   }
   public synchronized void remove(int ID)
   {
      int pos = findClient(ID);
      if (pos >= 0){
         BidServerThread toTerminate = clients[pos];
         System.out.println("Removing client thread " + ID + " at " + pos);

         if (pos < clientCount-1)
            for (int i = pos+1; i < clientCount; i++)
               clients[i-1] = clients[i];
         clientCount--;

         try{
             toTerminate.close();
         }
         catch(IOException ioe)
         {
             System.out.println("Error closing thread: " + ioe);
         }
         toTerminate = null;
         System.out.println("Client " + pos + " removed");
         notifyAll();
      }
   }

   private void addThread(Socket socket) throws InterruptedException
   {
      if (clientCount < clients.length){

         System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket);
         clients[clientCount] = new BidServerThread(this, socket);
         try{
            clients[clientCount].open();
            clients[clientCount].start();
            clientCount++;
         }
         catch(IOException ioe){
             System.out.println("Error opening thread: " + ioe);
          }
      }
      else
         System.out.println("Client refused: maximum " + clients.length + " reached.");
   }


   public static void main(String args[]) {
       BidServer server = null;
      if (args.length != 1)
         System.out.println("Usage: java BidServer port");
      else
         server = new BidServer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
   }

}
```

BidServerThread

```
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;


public class BidServerThread extends Thread
{  private BidServer       server    = null;
   private Socket           socket    = null;
   private int              ID        = -1;
   private DataInputStream  streamIn  =  null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;
   private Thread thread;
   private String auctionStart, bid,bidMade,clientBid;
   private String  invalidBid;
   int firstVal;

   ArrayList<Bid> items = new ArrayList<Bid>();
   //items.add(new Bid());
   //items

   //items
   //items.add(new Bid("Red Bike",0));






   public BidServerThread(BidServer _server, Socket _socket)
   {
      super();
      server = _server;
      socket = _socket;
      ID     = socket.getPort();



   }
   public void send(String msg)
   {
       try{

          streamOut.writeUTF(msg);
          streamOut.flush();
       }
       catch(IOException ioe)
       {
          System.out.println(ID + " ERROR sending: " + ioe.getMessage());
          server.remove(ID);
          thread=null;
       }
   }
   public int getID(){
       return ID;
   }

   public void run()
   {
      System.out.println("Server Thread " + ID + " running.");
      thread = new Thread(this);
      while (true){
         try{
             server.broadcast(ID, streamIn.readUTF());

             int pause = (int)(Math.random()*3000);
             Thread.sleep(pause);
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {
            System.out.println(e);
         }
         catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ID + " ERROR reading: " + ioe.getMessage());
            server.remove(ID);
            thread = null;
         }
      }
   }

   public void open() throws IOException, InterruptedException
   {
      streamIn = new DataInputStream(new
                        BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(new
                        BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
      String msg2 = "Welcome to the auction,do you wish to start?";
    streamOut.writeUTF(msg2);
    streamOut.flush();
    String auctionStart;
    String bid;
    String firstMessage = streamIn.readUTF().toLowerCase();
    CharSequence yes ="yes";
    CharSequence no = "no";
    if(firstMessage.contains(yes))
    {

      commenceBid();


    }

    else if(firstMessage.contains(no))
    {
        auctionStart ="Unfortunately, you cannot proceed. Closing connection";
        System.out.println(auctionStart);
        streamOut.writeUTF(auctionStart);
        streamOut.flush();
        int pause = (int)(Math.random()*2000);
        Thread.sleep(pause);
        socket.close();


    }
    else if(!firstMessage.contains(yes) && !firstMessage.contains(no)) 
    {
        System.out.println("Client has entered incorrect data");
        open();
    }


   }

   private void commenceBid() throws IOException {


         items.add(new Bid("Yellow Bike",0));
         items.add(new Bid("Red Bike",0));
         //items.add(new Bid("Green bike",0));


         String auctionStart = "Auction will commence now. First item is:\n" + items.get(0).getName();
         String bidCommence = "Make a bid, whole number please.";
         synchronized (server) {
                server.broadcast(ID, bidCommence);
         }

         System.out.println("item value is" + items.get(0).getValue());
         streamOut.writeUTF(auctionStart);
         streamOut.flush();
         streamOut.writeUTF(bidCommence);
         streamOut.flush();

         bidMade();


}
private void bidMade() throws IOException {

     bidMade = streamIn.readUTF();

     if(bidMade.matches(".*\\d.*"))
     {
         int bid = Integer.parseInt(bidMade); 

         if(bid <= items.get(0).getValue())
         {
             String lowBid = "Latest bid is too low, please bid higher than the current bid " + items.get(0).getValue();
             streamOut.writeUTF(lowBid);
             streamOut.flush();

             commenceBid();
         }
         if (bid > items.get(0).getValue()) {

             items.get(0).setValue(bid);
             String bidItem = "value of current bid is: " + items.get(0).getValue();
             streamOut.writeUTF(bidItem);
             streamOut.flush();
             System.out.println("Current bid: " + items.get(0).getValue());
             String continueBid = "If you want to make another bid, say yes";
             streamOut.writeUTF(continueBid);
             String continueBidReply = streamIn.readUTF();
             {
                 if(continueBidReply.contains("yes") || continueBidReply.contains("Yes"))
                 {
                     commenceBid();
                 }
                 if(continueBidReply.contains("No") || continueBidReply.contains("No"))
                 {
                     socket.close();
                 }
             }
             streamOut.flush();

        }


     }   

     else
     {
          invalidBid = "You have made an invalid bid, please choose a number";
          streamOut.writeUTF(invalidBid);
          streamOut.flush();


     }


}
public void close() throws IOException
   {
       if (socket != null)
        socket.close();

      if (streamIn != null)
        streamIn.close();

      if (streamOut != null)
        streamOut.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: I would use a debugger to see what is preventing additional clients. It appears you are starting multiple threads, one per client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BidServerThread.open()` is called before the thread is started in `BidServer.addThread()`. This blocks the BidServer (and prevents it from accepting other clients) until the call has returned.

`BidServerThread.open()` does various synchronous stuff interacting with the client ("do you wish to start?", "yes"/"no" etc.). It eventually calls itself recursively (loop) and it calls `commenceBid()` which in turn may call `bidMade()` which in turn may recur to `commenceBid()` in the course of *synchronous* interaction with the client. It is possible to have a scenario in which you have 3 interactions before this ends.

I guess, you could call `BidServerThread.open()` from `BidServerThread.run()` instead of in `BidServer.addThread()` in order for it to run in its thread asynchronously. (`Thread.start()` calls `Thread.run()`.)